# How to apply css styles to span using flutter_html

Tags: html, flutter

I'm using flutter_html package on my app to parse HTML from API. The html code is:

```
<p>Text text text text <span style="background: #FF0000; color: #FFFFFF; padding: 2px 5px; border-radius: 3px">XX</span> text text</p>
```

And it should print like https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHjCQ.png

But it prints this way https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWLZr.png

The max I get to this is patching flutter_html packe like this:

```
if(node.attributes.isNotEmpty){
              if(node.attributes['background'] != null){
                childStyle = childStyle.merge(TextStyle(

                    //backgroundColor: Color(int.parse(node.attributes['background']))));
                    background: Paint()
                      ..color = Color(int.parse(node.attributes['background']))
                      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
                      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                      ..strokeWidth = 2.0
                ));
              }
              if(node.attributes['color'] != null){
                childStyle = childStyle.merge(TextStyle(
                    color: Color(int.parse(node.attributes['color']))));
              }
              if(node.attributes['padding'] != null){
                childStyle = childStyle.merge(TextStyle(
                    wordSpacing: double.parse(node.attributes['padding'])));
              }
            }
```

But how can I add rounded border and padding?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

`flutter_html` currently doesn't support css, both inline and in the style tag. Version 1.0.0 has planned support for both of those use cases. It should be released towards the end of November 2019.

Source: I am the owner/prgrammer of the `flutter_html` package.

Comment: Is this already implemented yet? Using version ^1.0.0-pre.1 something like `<p><span style="color: #169179;"><strong>24423</strong></span></p>` does not result in a colored span for me. Reading the wiki though suggest it should? Maybe? :D